# How long do image_picker images stay in cache?

Tags: flutter, caching, imagepicker

Do they stay until the app is uninstalled or cache is cleared, or do the images get deleted at certain times by the os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the space available on the device to auto delete.

Please check the link below for more info

> Apps are strongly encouraged to keep their usage of cache space below the quota returned by StorageManager#getCacheQuotaBytes(java.util.UUID). If your app goes above this quota, your cached files will be some of the first to be deleted when additional disk space is needed. Conversely, if your app stays under this quota, your cached files will be some of the last to be deleted when additional disk space is needed.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()